# What is the real purpose of Redirect_Uri in OpenIdConnect?

Tags: redirect, azure-active-directory

I am trying to setup OpenID Connect Authentication (*Single-tenanted*) for my web application. I understand how Reply Url in AAD is supposed to work. AAD admin registers a web application with SignInUrl, ReplyUri, AppIdUri,.. Microsoft AAD handles the complete user experience to prompt & validate the credentials. An attacker may not be able to pose legitimate site attack (*since it is *.microsoftonline.com page*).

Questions:

1. What is the real purpose of Redirect_Uri in OpenIdConnect? Does it fight Redirect_Uri Attack?
2. I tried to send different Redirect_Uri from web client. Microsoft AAD fails by reply urls do not match error. But while refreshing the web application, it is signed in now. Should AAD not invalidate my attempt of logging in with illegitimate redirect uri?

Please suggest me how to view Redirect Uri. I would like to harness the real benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the real purpose of Redirect_Uri in OpenIdConnect?

From the [OpenID Connect, 3.1.2.1 Authentication Request](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest):

```
redirect_uri
    REQUIRED. Redirection URI to which the response will be sent.
    This URI MUST exactly match one of the Redirection URI values
    for the Client pre-registered at the OpenID Provider [...]
```

So, the purpose of `redirect_uri` is to tell the OpenID Provider (Azure AD, in your case) where the response to the request should be sent, after the user signs in.

> Does it fight Redirect_Uri Attack?

The parameter itself offer the functionality described above, it doesn't mitigate any attack. It is the responsibility of the client (i.e. your app) and the OpenID Provider (i.e. Azure AD) to ensure they are doing the right thing to prevent exposing the risk of an attack (including an attack related to redirections).

For example, if an OpenID Provider did not validate that the `redirect_uri` from the request exactly matches a redirection URI configured for the client, then an attacker might be able to construct an authorization request with a `redirect_uri` pointing to a URL controlled by the attacker, and then trick a user into triggering the request. The response to the request would then be sent to the attacker, rather than to the relying party the user *thinks* they're signing in to.

There are other attacks related to `redirect_uri` which could happen if the relying party (i.e. your app, in this case) exposed a vulnerability (for example, by enabling an open redirection attack, or by authorizing a reply URL which is not actually in your control).

Many of these (and other) attacks, as well as the current best practices to mitigate or prevent them, are described in [OAuth 2.0 Security Best Current Practice](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics/).

> I tried to send different Redirect_Uri from web client. Microsoft AAD fails by reply urls do not match error. But while refreshing the web application, it is signed in now. Should AAD not invalidate my attempt of logging in with illegitimate redirect uri?

This seems like there is an issue in your application. When Azure AD detects that the requested `redirect_uri` does not exactly match an authorized reply URI for the client, Azure AD does not redirect back to the client with an authorization code or any tokens.

It is possible that your app had already established a session previously, or is incorrectly processing the OpenID Connect flow. It's impossible to say without knowing the specific details of how the app is implemented.

Comment: Redirect_Uri does not behave well when I hosted my application in localhost even on different ports or same domain. So, it ignores Redirect_Uri validation, if I click on Sign-In despite the first Reply-Uri-Mismatch error. Only for localhost Urls

Comment: Microsoft AAD is my Open ID Provider now. It validates the reply-url-mismatch only when Urls are not localhost.

Comment: A detail that long eluded me with `redirect_uri` is that the provider can be configured with _multiple_ acceptable `redirect_uri`s.` (From the spec: "This URI MUST exactly match one of the Redirection URI values for the Client pre-registered at the OpenID Provider.") That is why the client / relaying party has to specify `redirect_uri` at all; it tells the provider which of the acceptable redirects should be called in the current instance.

Answer (score 1):

Now I think I found the mystery behind the signin-redirect_uri anomalies.

**Questions:**

1. What is the real purpose of Redirect_Uri in OpenIdConnect? Does it fight Redirect_Uri Attack?

   **[OP]** Yes, it does. If redirect_uri domain differs from AAD server Registration and web client, it invalidates the sign-in attempt.
2. I tried to send different Redirect_Uri from web client. Microsoft AAD fails by reply urls do not match error. But while refreshing the web application, it is signed in now. Should AAD not invalidate my attempt of logging in with illegitimate redirect uri?

   **[OP]** Redirect_Uri does not behave when I hosted my application in localhost even on different ports or same domain. So, it ignores Redirect_Uri validation, if I click on Sign-In despite the first Reply-Uri-Mismatch error.

Please note that Redirect_Uri does handle Open redirect attack if an attacker wants to redirect the victim to illegitimate page for re-entering the credentials.